# If URL contains query string in theme functions

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, themes

I'm trying to write a theme function for my WordPress website.

Basically I would like to include the jQuery library if the the URL has **?download**

Because it's the only page where jQuery script exist.. So I'm aiming to remove the library on the header for other pages (making the website loads faster is the ultimate goal here).

URL: /windows/post-name/?download

Is the following code correct?

```
{
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-lib', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array(), false, false );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress already comes bundled with jQuery. When you have a script that needs jQuery as a dependency, you pass it into `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Here is an example of enqueing a script that depends on jQuery:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

To read more about dependencies WordPress offers, here is the documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware that WordPress comes bundled with jQuery, I would like to remove it from pages that don't need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that no need for jQuery on other pages you can use hook to disable jquery except **?download** pages by hook ( for example in functions.php theme file ):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    
    ( isset( $_GET[ 'download' ] ) ) ? wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ) : wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    
}, 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks, what does 99 means at the end?

Comment: @user3152370 - The 99 is the priority of when this action will execute. The lower the number, the earlier the execution and the higher the number, the later the execution. So the 99 is making sure jQuery is removed last after everything is executed.